# error: invalid effective address

Tags: assembly, nasm

I don't know why my NASM assembler keeps giving me the error that I got an invalid effective address in my code. The problem lies in the following piece of code: `mov    eax, dword [lst + (bl * DOUBLE_WORD)]`. I'm just trying to add the product of a constant and whatever is stored in the 8-bit BL register to the address value represented by `lst`. Am I not allowed to do that? Well, in the book I'm reading, this is exactly the way the author does it.

```
; ************************************************************************
; Assembler: NASM
;
; This program sums the values of all elements of a double word array.
;
; ************************************************************************

section .data
    EXIT_SUCCESS equ 0            ; The exit status code for success
    SYS_EXIT     equ 0x3C         ; The value for the exit system call
    DOUBLE_WORD  equ 4            ; A double word is 4 bytes

    lst          dd  10, 20, 2, 1 ; A 4-element array
    size         db  4            ; The size of the array
    sum          dd  0            ; This is where we're going to store the sum

section .text
global _start
_start:
    nop
    mov    bl, 0 ; The index to keep track of the element we're working with
_loop:
    ; error: invalid effective address
    mov    eax, dword [lst + (bl * DOUBLE_WORD)]
    add    dword [sum], eax
    inc    bl
    cmp    bl, byte [size] ; Compare the index to the size
    jne    _loop           ; If the index value is not equal to the size,
                           ; keep looping

    ; x/dw &sum

    ; exit
    mov    rax, SYS_EXIT
    mov    rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
    syscall

; ************************************************************************

%if 0

Compile and run:

nasm -f elf64 -F dwarf -g -o demo.o demo.asm -l demo.lst && \
ld -g -o a.out demo.o && \
rm demo.o && \
./a.out

%endif
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes)  That was my attempt at writing up a canonical answer to addressing-mode questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: change `bl` to `ebx`.

Long answer: in x86, the addressing mode you're using is called [SIB](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#SIB) (scale index base), where the effective address is of the form `base + index * scale + displacement`, where `base` and `index` are general registers like `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx`, or `edx`, and `scale` is 1, 2, 4, or 8, and `displacement` is an immediate number. (Each of these components is optional.)

`bl` isn't one of the registers you can use for the index.

Comment: I am guessing calculation must be done on effective address at runtime. Is `base + index * scale + displacement` faster than doing `imul eax, index, scale` `add eax, base` `add eax, displacement`?